# How to draw inside a TikZ node, using node style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I would like to define a node style, so that the node will look like the LaTeX symbol `\oplus`, i.e. a circle with lines from north to south, and east to west.  (I also have more complicated examples in mind.)

I think that I should draw the lines in the `execute at end node`, or `after mode path` arguments, but nothing I have tried seems to work.  The code I have in mind is something like this:

```
\tikzstyle{foo}=[circle,draw,execute at end node={\draw ??????}]
```

To rephrase the question:  How can one do arbitrary drawing within a node, and define this as a style?  In particular, how do you get the coordinates of the current node in a style?

Comment: a tip: you can use backticks `\`` to mark your inline code as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All TikZ node shapes are defined using lower-level PGF code. This is described in the `pgfmanual` in section 75.5 *Declaring New Shapes*, on page 625 of the v2.1 manual.

You can use the existing code of the circle shape as a base and add the lines to it. The code can be found in the file `${TEXMF}/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex`.

Here the way I would do it:

### Shape declaration:

```
\pgfdeclareshape{oplus}
%
% Shaped like '\oplus' math symbol. Based on 'circle' shape
%
{%
  % All anchors are taken from the 'circle' shape:
  \inheritsavedanchors[from={circle}]%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{center}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{mid}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{base}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{north}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{south}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{west}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{east}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{mid west}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{mid east}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{base west}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{base east}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{north west}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{south west}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{north east}%
  \inheritanchor[from={circle}]{south east}%
  \inheritanchorborder[from={circle}]%
  %
  % Only the background path is different
  %
  \backgroundpath{%
    % First the existing 'circle' code:
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \ifdim\pgf@xb<\pgf@yb%
      \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@yb%
    \else%
      \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@xb%
    \fi%
    \pgfpathcircle{\centerpoint}{\pgfutil@tempdima}%
    %
    % Now the | and -- lines:
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}}%
    \pgflineto{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}}}%
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}}%
    \pgflineto{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}}%
  }%
}
```

### Usage example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfshape_oplus}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw=blue,shape=oplus] {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Result:

[image: Result]

You might also want to draw the additional lines in the `\foregroundpath` instead. For this see the `forbidden sign` shape in the file `pgflibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex` is an good example.

Comment: very good answer: the right method, the right code.  But note the [forbidden sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol) shape is backwards!

Comment: @Matthew: You mean the line is drawn in the wrong angle, do you? That's something which should be reported to the PGF/TikZ author. Nevertheless the code of it is a good example for having a circle as background path and the other lines in the foreground.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  I did report it to the mailing list a while back (google tells me it was Feb 2009).  Maybe I should follow up on that since it's just a one-line patch—unless now you want it to be an *option* to have it backwards!

Comment: @Matthew: Yeah, backwards compatibility (wow what a pun! :-) ) is always an issue even with smaller stuff like this.

Comment: @Martin: Tell me about it.  The new pgfmath engine has introduced bugs in lots of the graphs that I use for teaching. :-(

Comment: @Matthew: Yes I heard from that, especially the `{\n}^2` vs. `\n^2` bug.

Comment: @Martin: *c'est ça, exactement.*

Comment: @Matthew Thanks because I did not know this problem. I know only the problem with negative values and `x^2` but in which case do you put braces around `\n`? The interesting case is to hide parentheses with braces inside coordinates.

Comment: @Matthew: what new pgfmath engine is this? Does pgf have lots of bugs? Alarming...

Comment: @Faheem: Don't be alarmed.  It can be worked around by replacing `\x^n` with `(-\x)^n` in most cases.  They may have actually fixed it in CVS; I haven't checked lately (CVS was recently down for quite a while while sourceforge was under attack).  This is the only bug I've found in PGF which I otherwise love!  I apologize for hijacking the comment thread as well.

Comment: @Martin: thanks very much for this answer.  It is exactly what I needed, and gives the tools to generalise in the ways I wanted to.

Answer (score 7):

A possibility :

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \tikzset{oplus/.style={path picture={% 
      \draw[black]
       (path picture bounding box.south) -- (path picture bounding box.north) 
       (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east);
      }}} 
    \node[oplus,fill=blue!10,draw=blue,thick,circle] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: oplus]

It's possible to send the cross in the background and to change the color

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tikzset{oplus/.style={path picture={%
 \begin{pgfonlayer}{background} 
 \draw[red,opacity=.5]
  (path picture bounding box.south) -- (path picture bounding box.north) 
  (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east);
\end{pgfonlayer}}}
}
\node[oplus,draw=blue,thick,circle](a) {TEST}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: oplus 2]

Now your code `execute at end node` is not good in this case. This code modifies the content of the node. You can try the next code :

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{foo/.style ={circle,draw, execute at end node={\ #1}}} 
    \node[foo=bad](A) at (2,3){good};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Interesting is `execute at begin node=$` and `execute at end node=$`

Now if my answer is not what you want, you can define new shape like `shape =oplus` like in the other answer from Martin.