# What is a good BPMN tool in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm looking for a nice package (or tool) to write BPMN diagrams directly into my documents. However, I had no luck so far.

I found several tools that may help doing the diagrams, and then exporting to SVG or PDF directly. However, I want something more native to LaTeX, like Tikz.

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168828/tikz-implementation-for-bpmn-2-0), but is deleted and I have no access to it. (Also, I'm not sure if this question doesn't belong here, and that is why that question got deleted in the first place. If that is the case, putting some kind of message in this question would be a good idea instead of just sending the question to oblivion.)

Also, found a couple of initial directions, like:

- [Draw inside nodes to get BPMN gateway shapes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45645/draw-inside-nodes-to-get-bpmn-gateway-shapes)
- or [this blog post](https://blog.kubovy.eu/2013/10/04/latex-tikz-bpmn-2-0-gateways/)

But I couldn't find a full package that may help doing a full diagram, and easing the maintenance, or work load to start from scratch to create diagrams.

**Any help or pointers on where to look are appreciated.**

Comment: I you don't find a specific package for it (I am not aware of one), then just use `tikz` as in the two examples you linked to.

Comment: Try http://www.tikzedt.org/ with my library you found :) There is also one for events which are more challenging (https://blog.kubovy.eu/2013/09/30/latex-tikz-bpmn-2-0-events/)

Comment: soo @user2564748 the link you posted (just like the link in the OP) are both returning a 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen tikz `tikz-bpmn` package here? 
https://github.com/behnaaz/gdeploy/blob/master/francegrilles/tikz-bpmn.sty

Examples of how to use it can be found here:
https://github.com/behnaaz/gdeploy/blob/master/francegrilles/slides.tex

```
>     \node[event] (start) {};
>       \node[task,node distance=3em,right=of start] (updglite) { Update \\ all nodes };
>       \draw[sequence,->] (start) -- (updglite);
```

Comment: This is the library itself can you add an example about its usage?

Comment: I put some small piece here but I post a link for much better examples.